# How to fix anchor tag landing in wrong position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I’m new to JavaScript. Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find any solution for my needs.

When clicking on the anchor tag, it leads to my desired position. However, I have another anchor tag that is meant to link to the same position as the other. If I click this (After I’ve already clicked the other anchor tag that leads to the same position as the one I’m about to click now), it does NOT lead me to my desired position.

I understand it must be because I’m using `hashchange`. I tried using `click` but that returns -1 for `console.log(document.URL.indexOf(“#”));` instead of 58 when using `hashchange`.

I figure the `click` logic is on the right path but I don’t understand why it’s not doing what I expect. (That being: click runs after you’ve clicked something clickable on the page).

I also tried using `setTimeout` but I couldn’t figure out a way to correctly manipulate it to ‘restart’ my `fixedAnchor` function.

```
    function fixedAnchor() {
        // if (location.hash.length !== 0) {
            window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY - 130);
            console.log(document.URL.indexOf("#"));
            // console.log(document.URL.indexOf("#") > -1 & document.URL.indexOf("#") <= 58);
            // if (document.URL.indexOf("#") > -1 & document.URL.indexOf("#") < 58) {
            //  console.log(document.URL.indexOf("#") > -1);
                offSetAnchor();
            // }
        // }
    }

    function offSetAnchor() {
        if (document.URL.indexOf("#") != 58){
            window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY - 130);
        }
        // setTimeout(function(){
        //  window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY - 130);
        //  // fixedAnchor();
        // }, 1000);
    }

    window.addEventListener('hashchange', fixedAnchor);
    // window.addEventListener('click', fixedAnchor);
```

Comment: Can you set up a JSFiddle or a snippet here to show us the whole page with HTML and all?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with named anchors using just HTML. Please find code below in which 2 links take to same position

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <a href="#gohere">click 1 to gohere</a>
    <p>Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
    <p><a href="#gohere">click 1 to gohere</a>Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
    <p>Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
    <p>Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
    <p id="gohere"> Selected Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a great use for jQuery's `.click()` event handler. You can create an anchor class for the anchor elements and bind the `.click()` event.

```
$(".anchor").click(function(){
    window.scrollTo(0, 130)
})
```

Here's [a working example](http://codepen.io/arebe/pen/bepJrR).

You can do something similar without jQuery with `addEventListener('onClick')`.